# Elixir: Dynamic infix operator

Tags: elixir

I'm trying to write a simple module function that takes an expression as a string like `"123 + 45"` and returns an answer. So:

```
Calculator.calculate("123 + 45")
# => 168
```

I thought about just splitting the string on `(" ")` to get the integers and the operator, then basically calling `Code.eval_string` on it. Here was my first naive attempt:

```
defmodule Calculator do
  def calculate(str) do
    [x, oper, y] = String.split(str, " ")
    formula = "a = fn (c, d) -> c operator d end; a.(c, d)"
    {answer, _ } = Code.eval_string(formula, [
      c: String.to_integer(x),
      operator: String.to_atom(oper),
      d: String.to_integer(y)
    ])
    answer
  end
end
```

Then, in running it, I receive this error:

```
** (CompileError) nofile:1: undefined function c/1
    (elixir) src/elixir_fn.erl:10: anonymous fn/3 in :elixir_fn.expand/3
    (stdlib) lists.erl:1239: :lists.map/2
    (elixir) src/elixir_fn.erl:14: :elixir_fn.expand/3
```

I couldn't figure out why `c` was being evaluated as a function. I suspect that it has to do with the `operator` variable in the anonymous function. I confirmed that by rewriting it with a hardcoded operator:

```
defmodule Calculator do
  def calculate(str) do
    [x, _, y] = String.split(str, " ")
    formula = "a = fn (c, d) -> c + d end; a.(c, d)"
    {answer, _ } = Code.eval_string(formula, [
      c: String.to_integer(x),
      d: String.to_integer(y)
    ])
    answer
  end
end
```

Indeed, this produces the expected result. The question is:

**Why did the presence of the `operator` variable binding in the anonymous function cause `c` to be evaluated as a function?**

It appears from the docs on [`Code.eval_string`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Code.html#eval_string/3) makes it seem as though the variable bindings can be just about anything as long as they're found in the keyword list that is the second argument to `eval_string`.

In my second attempt, I thought about trying to convert the operator from the input string into an atom and convert the operator from an infix to a function call (i.e., from `1 + 3` to something like `1.(:+, [3])`. But that doesn't appear to be valid syntax.

So my second question is:

**Is it possible to write an expression with an infix operator such as `+` as a function, and then to be able do dynamically define that operator as an atom?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Why did the presence of the `operator` variable binding in the anonymous function cause `c` to be evaluated as a function?

The code `c operator d` is parsed as `c(operator(d))` by `Code.eval_string`, just like it would in normal Elixir, which means both `c` and `operator` must be functions of arity 1 for that expression to make sense. You wouldn't expect the following code to work, would you?

```
c = 1
operator = :+
d = 2
a = fn (c, d) -> c operator d end; a.(c, d)
```

> Is it possible to write an expression with an infix operator such as `+` as a function, and then to be able do dynamically define that operator as an atom?

Since these operators are just functions defined in `Kernel` module, you can use `apply/3` to call it:

```
iex(1)> c = 1
1
iex(2)> operator = :+
:+
iex(3)> d = 2
2
iex(4)> apply(Kernel, operator, [c, d])
3
```

So in your original code, just replace `c operator d` with `apply(Kernel, operator, [c, d])`.

There's also no need of `eval_string` here.

```
iex(1)> [a, b, c] = String.split("123 * 456", " ")
["123", "*", "456"]
iex(2)> a = String.to_integer(a)
123
iex(3)> b = String.to_atom(b)
:*
iex(4)> c = String.to_integer(c)
456
iex(5)> apply(Kernel, b, [a, c])
56088
```